# How to make page auto-update like facebook does, without using setTimeout() or setInterval()

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Is it possible without using `setInterval()` or `setTimeout()`? How to update page like Facebook page?

If I open Facebook in my web browser, the page automatically updates whenever any new post is added by other friends. How can I achieve this? When i use `setInterval()` or `setTimeout()`, the page became heavy. Thanks in advance.

```
setInterval(ajaxCall1, 3000);
function ajaxcall1 {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'echo_file.php', 
        datatype: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            seriesOptions = data;
            createChart();
        },
    });
```

Comment: You can either do a polling like you did above or use websockets which is a bit more complicated but only updates when something changed.

Comment: thanks for the command.I have a lot of div to update using ajax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using web sockets to push data to a client is a better solution to AJAX polling.

This allows the server to notice when changes occur and actively push the data to the relevant clients. That gets rid of the unnecessary load placed both on the server and client caused by sending repeated requests every few seconds.

A popular web socket solution is a combination of NodeJs and Socket IO. Links to these resources can be found here:

http://nodejs.org/
http://socket.io/

These are relatively easy to pick up and you can get started in a matter of minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>BargePoller</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
      body{ background:#000;color:#fff;font-size:.9em; }
      .msg{ background:#aaa;padding:.2em; border-bottom:1px #000 solid}
      .old{ background-color:#246499;}
      .new{ background-color:#3B9957;}
    .error{ background-color:#992E36;}
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    function addmsg(type, msg){
        /* Simple helper to add a div.
        type is the name of a CSS class (old/new/error).
        msg is the contents of the div */
        $("#messages").append(
            "<div class='msg "+ type +"'>"+ msg +"</div>"
        );
    }

    function waitForMsg(){
        /* This requests the url "msgsrv.php"
        When it complete (or errors)*/
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "msgsrv.php",

            async: true, /* If set to non-async, browser shows page as "Loading.."*/
            cache: false,
            timeout:50000, /* Timeout in ms */

            success: function(data){ /* called when request to barge.php completes */
                addmsg("new", data); /* Add response to a .msg div (with the "new" class)*/
                setTimeout(
                    waitForMsg, /* Request next message */
                    1000 /* ..after 1 seconds */
                );
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
                addmsg("error", textStatus + " (" + errorThrown + ")");
                setTimeout(
                    waitForMsg, /* Try again after.. */
                    15000); /* milliseconds (15seconds) */
            }
        });
    };

    $(document).ready(function(){
        waitForMsg(); /* Start the inital request */
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="messages">
        <div class="msg old">
            BargePoll message requester!
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[More Details](http://www.xphp.info/php-tutorial/long-polling/)

Comment: An AJAX op per second per user probably isn't very scalable.